# Access files in storage folder only through Auth Middleware and Token based authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have following folder in my Laravel website.

> /storage/Asset/Media

This folder can have info like below

/storage/Asset/Media/1/abc.png

/storage/Asset/Media/2/abc.png

Here 1 or 2 is the folder names.

I have following code to secure the folder so that nobody can access the folder without authentication

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/storage/Asset/Media/{ID}/{eded}', array(
        'as' => 'Files',
        'uses' => 'User\Account\Media\MediaController@DownloadMedia',
    ));
});
```

so in this way nobody can access the files until user's session is not expired in a browser.

Issue is in Android, so now nobody can access the files due to Auth Middleware.

Can somebody suggest the approach such that, files can be accessible to download via Token Based Authentication(through Android) and also using Auth Controller(through Website)?

Comment: As per my understanding you need to set token into header at the time of login. If anyone is looking for any resources they need to send token into header every time. and if token is validated then provide the resources.

Comment: Yes. Issue we I already have set the path for resources under `auth Middleware`. So how can i do it for `auth:api` ?

Comment: Nothing you need to do, your middleware will do the authentication, now middleware is the entry point, if token validated then only api will be called.otherwise it will returned from middleware.

Comment: In your controller just need to check if request is normal or from Ajax

if ($request->ajax()) {
    return response()->json($json);
}

return view('normal.view', compact('data'));

Comment: Have you tried Database Sessions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use any other config in `routes.php`, everything will work just fine if You follow this guide:

The easiest solution would be to create column named `api_token` is `users` table. Then when trying to access resource from android device, just add `?api_token=<token>` to Your URL, where `<token>` is a `api_token` column in Your `users` table.

For example:
`domain.com/storage/Asset/Media/1/2?api_token=123hello4secret`

System will try to search for user record with `api_token == 123hello4secret`, so just put that `123hello4secret` into Your user `api_token` field.

---

If You wonder why You should `api_token` as column name, the answer is here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a38acf7ee2882d831a3b9a1361a710e70ffa31e/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php#L45 Laravel will try to authorize You using `api_token` if it is found in request fields.

---

Also You can use HTTP headers to authorize with token:
Header example:

```
Authorization: Bearer 123hello4secret
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that by default 'storage' folder is not accessible anyway - only 'public' folder is publicly accessible. Therefore, you can use any URLs for file download controller.

You need two routes - one for cookie-based authentications (web users) and one for stateless (token) sessions:

```
// URL can be anything you want
Route::get('downloads/{ID}/{eded}', [
        'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],
        'as' => 'Files',
        'uses' => 'MediaController@DownloadMedia',
]); 

// For API tokens, use 'api' guard of Auth middleware
// URL has to be different, too
Route::get('api/downloads/{ID}/{eded}', [
        'middleware' => ['auth:api'],
        'as' => 'Files',
        'uses' => 'MediaController@DownloadMedia',
]);
```

You also need to add a token field to your users table. Add a line to your users table migration:

```
$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
```

Then, you need to generate this token. If you want to use the same token (no expiration or refresh), you could generate it when a new user is being created. You could have this in your User class:

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    User::creating(function ($user) {
        $user->api_token = str_random(60);
    });
}
```

Otherwise, you could force the token to be refreshed on every login attempt (postLogin in AuthController) or maybe have a separate controller method that exchanges email and password for a token.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap a new Route within an `auth:api` Middleware

This is very simple using Laravel's API authentication.

Answer (score 0):

you can put .htaccess file in /storage/Asset/Media

with code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

you can access files in php but direct link to file will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your users table make a nullable column `api_token`

Now every time user login via the Api, set this `api_token` in db and send this to the Api consumer.

Now on further request the Api consumer will send back the token in request header. So just configure the Authenticate Middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
      if(!empty($request->header('Auth-Token'))) {
        $api_token = $request->header('Auth-Token');
        $user = User::where('api_token', $api_token)->first();
        if(is_null($user)) //Unauthorize: write response to return 
      } elseif ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
     }

      return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to add functionality for authorization via `api_token`. It's out of the box functionality, see my answer.