# Laravel 5 - How to access folder,sub folder,css,js uploaded in storage only for loged in users

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authorization, laravel-storage

I have a set of directories in my Laravel storage directory.
path is `\storage\app\public\docs`. 
Inside the `docs` directory there are a set of folders that contain HTML,CSS,JS.

I want to access those folders/files if users is logedin.
here is my route:

```
Route::get('storage/{directory}/{subdirectory}/{page}', function ($directory,$subdirectory,$page)
    {
                if(!Auth::check()){
                    die('Unauth access');
                }            
                $path = storage_path('app/public/' . $directory.'/'.$subdirectory.'/'.$page);
                if (!File::exists($path)) {
                    abort(404);
                }
                $file = File::get($path);    
                $type = File::mimeType($path);
                $response = Response::make($file, 200);
                $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
                return $response;
    });
```

example:

url:

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/docs/62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eaba4c/index.html
```

The response is loading success.
but there are some external css and js are caled in the index.html. 
But they are not load in the response.

The js and css are include in css and js directory that contain in `62199911-74c61aaf688c0d374f23253218a12a9b81eaba4c` directory

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to allow assess each files and folder in storage directory when user is logedin(not for guess users).

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372317/access-files-in-storage-folder-only-through-auth-middleware-and-token-based-auth